# Spill formula to lookup matching row data in one sheet with column data in another and evaluate corresponding cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, one with month/year data spilt across the row from **I2** using the formula `=EDATE(DATE(2017,8,1), SEQUENCE(1,401,0))` and another with month and expenditure data running down the columns.

I'd like to insert a spill formula in to **I3** in the first sheet to lookup the month from **I2#** with the corresponding month in the second sheet and if found, multiply the values in columns D and E.

With the data being in rows on one sheet and columns in the other I'm not sure how to tackle this.

The following is a sample of the data in the second sheet:

| Month | Projected Costs | Actual Costs | Monthly Employees | Monthly Per Employee Costs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nov-19 | £2,000 | £3,000 | 5 | £600 |
| Dec-19 | £10,000 |  | 11 | £909 |
| Jan-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Feb-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Mar-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Apr-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| May-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Jun-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Jul-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Aug-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Sep-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |
| Oct-20 | £18,000 |  | 19 | £947 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `I2#` correctly in your formula, the output will be the same size/dimensions as I2#. One way of doing it would be separate lookups on columns D and E respectively which are then multiplied together.

```
=XLOOKUP(I2#, Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!D:D) * XLOOKUP(I2#, Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!E:E)
```

(You might wish to add an `IFERROR()` function around the outside of that to clear up all the months where data isn't found)